# Ball released from accelerating car, and observed by observer in two different frames

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, inertial-frames

Consider an accelerating car in which u r sitting and holding a ball and a guy stand outside.
Now if u release the ball, what will be the motion of the ball seen by u and the guy? Now switch of earth's gravity, now what is the motion of ball seen by you and guy. Another case is considering elevator which is accelerating upward and the bwll is dropped inside and one is outside the elevator, now what will be the motion of ball seen by observer in and out of elevator?

Comment: What are your ideas as to the answers to your questions?

Comment: In the following conditions, is any one for which, the ball will seen as stationary.

Answer (score 1):

For you the ball will fall down with an acceleration g and move left with an acceleration equal to car ( if the car is going right for an inertial observer who is out of the car (obviously)). The path would be complicated. For the ground observer the ball would be going right with a final velocity and also going down with an acceleration g. The path will be a parabola.

If you switch off gravity , then for you the ball would go left with an acceleration equal to that of the car. For the ground person it shall be going with a constant velocity after you release it without any vertical fall.

Comment: I think your answer is wrong

Comment: @Utkarshfutous  OK. Then correctt it

Comment: The ball will move with an _acceleration_ equal to the car?  We should start dropping things from accelerating vehicles for free energy.

Comment: @JMac  if I am accelerating at a and the ball isn't accelerating with me  will I not see it accelerating it at a. When the ball was in the observers hand it was not accelerating W.r.t to the observer. When it is left the observer will see the ball accelerating to the left.

Comment: @JMac  If I accelerate to the right in a car. The surroundings accelerate to the left. What's free energy here...

Comment: Being noted what Jmac said I think the path is fine actually I got confused since there is no left/right in question so I must have  thought the other way so I got different answer

Comment: @Utkarshfutous  Oh! That's OK. What do you think the answer is right ?

Comment: @Shashaank You should think about rewording this.  It sounds like the ball is keeping up with the car (especially since "left" is an arbitrary direction you chose and never specified as the opposite direction of the car's movement).

Comment: @JMac  OK I shall edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the car, a ball and Mohapatra are moving to the left and accelerating to the left relative to a stationary observer, Guy, on the ground with magnitude $a$.

Mohapatra is in the car, holding a ball and not moving relative to the car.

At some instant when the car and Mohapatra are moving to the left at a velocity $\vec v_{\rm drop}$, Mohapatra lets go of the ball.
At the instant of release the ball is not moving relative to Mohapatra but Guy  sees the ball moving to the left with velocity $\vec v_{\rm drop}$.

Guy on the ground now sees the ball undergo motion consisting of a constant velocity to the left (no horizontal forces) and an acceleration $\vec g$ downwards due to the attraction of the ball by the Earth.
This is the parabolic motion of a projectile shown in green on the diagram.

[image]

Mohapatra sees the sum of two accelerated motions.
Acceleration of free fall $\vec g$ downwards and an acceleration $\vec a$ to the right equal in magnitude to the acceleration of the car relative to the ground.
Mohapatra will see the ball drop and move to the right along a straight line path (red on the diagram) with acceleration of magnitude $\sqrt{a^2+g^2}$ at an angle to the vertical of $\tan^{-1} \left ( \dfrac {a}{g}\right)$.

Switching off gravity will result in the motions shown by the dots at the top of the diagram.

Guy on the ground will see the ball move to the left along a horizontal path with a constant velocity $\vec v_{\rm drop}$.
Mohapatra in the car will see the ball accelerate horizontally to the right with an acceleration $\vec a$.

I both cases Mohapatra is in a non-inertial frame of reference and could reason that there is a horizontal (pseudo)force acting on the ball to the right, $m \vec a$ , where $m$ is the mass of the ball.

---

Hopefully you can now answer your own last few questions?